# JPA 1:N relationship removing child does not remove it from parent

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have the following objects:

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Entity(name="Group")
public class Group {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "GROUP_ID")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="NAME")
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(
            targetEntity = Product.class,
            mappedBy = "groupId",
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            fetch = FetchType.EAGER,
            orphanRemoval = true
    )
    private List<Product> products = new ArrayList<>();

    public Group(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
```

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity(name="Product")
public class Product {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @NotNull
    @Column(name="PRODUCT_ID")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="NAME")
    private String name;

    @Column(name="DESCRIPTION")
    private String description;

    @Column(name="PRICE")
    private double price;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name = "JOIN_PRODUCT_CART",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "PRODUCT_ID", referencedColumnName = "PRODUCT_ID")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "CART_ID", referencedColumnName = "CART_ID")}
    )
    private List<CartEntity> carts = new ArrayList<>();

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "GROUP_ID")
    private Group groupId;

    public Product(String name, String description, double price) {
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
        this.price = price;
    }

    public Product(String name, String description, double price, Group groupId) {
        this(name, description, price);
        this.groupId = groupId;
    }

    public void addToCart(CartEntity cart) {
        this.carts.add(cart);
        cart.getProductsList().add(this);
    }

    public void addGroup(Group group) {
        group.getProducts().add(this);
        this.groupId = group;
    }
```

```
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity(name = "cart")
public class CartEntity {

    @Id
    @NotNull
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "CART_ID")
    private Long id;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "carts")
    private List<Product> productsList = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addProduct(Product product) {
        productsList.add(product);
        product.getCarts().add(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        CartEntity that = (CartEntity) o;
        return id.equals(that.id);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(id);
    }
}
```

Now, when I have the following test:

```
public class ProductDaoTestSuite {
    @Autowired
    private ProductDao productDao;
    @Autowired
    private CartDaoStub cartDaoStub;
    @Autowired
    private GroupDao groupDao;

    @Test
    public void testDeleteProduct() {
        // Given
        Product product = new Product("test", "testProduct", 100.0);
        Group group = new Group("group1");
        CartEntity cart = new CartEntity();

        product.addGroup(group);
        cart.addProduct(product);

        // When
        groupDao.save(group);
        productDao.save(product);
        cartDaoStub.save(cart);

        Long groupId = group.getId();
        Long productId = product.getId();
        Long cartId = cart.getId();

        productDao.deleteById(productId);

        // Then
        Assert.assertTrue(cartDaoStub.findById(cartId).isPresent());
        Assert.assertEquals(0, cartDaoStub.findById(cartId).get().getProductsList().size());

        Assert.assertTrue(groupDao.findById(groupId).isPresent());
        Assert.assertEquals(0, groupDao.findById(groupId).get().getProducts().size());
```

Following product deletion, I would expect association with it in group and cart to disappear (product to disappear from their List relationship fields). However, that is not happening at the moment. When I use Group/Cart Dao to pull group & cart from the DB after product deletion, they still have product in their Lists, while product when pulled from the DB is returned as null.
I have tried to add "orphanRemoval = true" value for @OneToMany adnotation, but it did not seem to work for Group entity.

What am I doing wrong?

I have started experimenting with adding all types of cascade (except for REMOVE) to @ManyToOne on Product class, but so far no luck.

Comment: The entities `group` and `cart` represent the state before deletion. Re-fetch the entites from database and the newly fetched entities will no longer have the deleted product.

Comment: I am doing that by cartDaoStub.findById(cartId) & groupDao.findById(groupId), and these freshly fetched entities still have product in their lists.

Comment: That is strange... by conclusion, the `product`-entity should still be stored in the database. Is this correct?

Comment: Yeah, it is strange. Entity product after deletion is no longer present in the database. Does it change anything, that I am using a H2 database?

Comment: It should not... did you create the schema by hand or is it auto-generated by hibernate? Normally, there should be foreign key constraints on the join-tables, thus the deletion should be rejected by the database since the database row is referenced by another row.

Comment: The DB was created by hand, but I did not create any tables in it - I allowed Hibernate to work its magic there.

Comment: Your implementation of the equals and hashcode methods is a bit dangerous here. The ID is used in both methods, but it will change once the object is persisted to the database. That means that the hashCodes will change after you call the methods         product.addGroup(...) and cart.addProduct(...). I don't believe that causes the problems you are seeing, but you should at least be aware of the issue...

Answer (score 2):

**For 1:N**, yours should work just fine with minor adjustment.

**The reason why it fails:** Upon doing **"groupDao.save(group);"**  this **group** is now in the **persistence context** and calling **"groupDao.findById(groupId).get().getProducts().size()"** would return the copy which is from the persistence context.

**To solve this:** simply add: entityManager.flush(); and entityManager.clear(); before the Assert

I would like to demonstrate it with this Integration Test

```
    @Test
    @Transactional
    public void deleteProduct_groupShouldNowBeEmpty() {
        ProductGroup group = groupRepository.findById("0001").orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("id not found"));
        Assert.assertEquals(1, group.getProducts().size());

        Product product = productRepository.findById("0001").orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("id not found"));
        productRepository.delete(product);

        entityManager.flush();
        entityManager.clear();

        Assert.assertEquals(0, productRepository.findAll().size());
        Assert.assertEquals(0, groupRepository.findById("0001").get().getProducts().size());
    }
```

If we are to remove the first 2 lines, then we won't need to flush and clear. Like this.

```
    @Test
    @Transactional
    public void deleteProduct_groupShouldNowBeEmpty() {
        Product product = productRepository.findById("0001").orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("id not found"));
        productRepository.delete(product);

        Assert.assertEquals(0, productRepository.findAll().size());
        Assert.assertEquals(0, groupRepository.findById("0001").get().getProducts().size());
    }
```

**For N:M**, since there would be another table where product is being referenced, then we would need to delete the records from that table first before deleting the product.

N:M is a bit tricky so if I can suggest domain changes, here how I'll do it. (The integration test is at the bottom.)

I'll add a separate entity: **CartItem**
which is associated to a **Product** and **Cart**

```
@Entity
public class CartItem {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
    private String id;

    @ManyToOne
    private Product product;

    @ManyToOne
    private Cart cart;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    // Required by JPA
    protected CartItem() {}

}
```

And for the Product Entity: add a bidirectional relationship with CartItem

```
@Entity
public class Product {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
    private String id;

    private String name;

    private String description;

    private BigDecimal price;

    @ManyToOne
    private ProductGroup group;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "product")
    private List<CartItem> cartItems;

    public List<CartItem> getCartItems() {
        return cartItems;
    }

    // Required by JPA
    protected Product() {}
}
```

Then, retrieve the product (using Join Fetch to avoid N+1, since later will be looping through each cartItem)

```
public interface ProductRepository extends JpaRepository<Product, String> {

    @Query("SELECT product FROM Product product JOIN FETCH product.cartItems")
    Optional<Product> findProduct(String Id);

}
```

create another query inside CartItemRepository to delete cartItems in bulk by ids

```
public interface CartItemRepository extends JpaRepository<CartItem, String> {

    @Modifying
    @Query("DELETE FROM CartItem cartItem WHERE cartItem.id IN :ids")
    void deleteByIds(@Param("ids") List<String> ids);

}
```

Lastly here's the integration test to wrap everthing up:

```
@Test
@Transactional
public void deleteProduct_associatedWithCart() {
    Cart cart = cartRepository.findById("0001").get();
    Assert.assertEquals(1, cart.getCartItems().size());

    Product product = productRepository.findProduct("0001").orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("id not found"));
    List<String> cartItemIds = product.getCartItems().stream()
            .map(CartItem::getId)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    cartItemRepository.deleteByIds(cartItemIds);
    productRepository.delete(product);

    entityManager.flush();
    entityManager.clear();

    Assert.assertEquals(0, productRepository.findAll().size());
    Assert.assertEquals(0, groupRepository.findById("0001").get().getProducts().size());

    Assert.assertEquals(0, cartItemRepository.findAll().size());
    Assert.assertEquals(0, cartRepository.findById("0001").get().getCartItems().size());
}
```

I've used DBUnit for this integration test so I think it would also be helpful to share the dataset.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <dataset>
        <product_group id="0001" name="product group with 1 product"/>
        <product id="0001" group_id="0001" />
    
        <cart id="0001" />
        <cart_item id="0001" product_id="0001" cart_id="0001" />
    </dataset>
```

Comment: I believe this answer is correct. The findById method finds that the Cart and the Group exist because the query returns them. But while it is processing the ResultSet it notices that these entities already exist in the first-level-cache. Therefore, the object is returned from the cache rather than re-querying 1:M or N:M relationships. A flush & clear should cause your test to work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

When you `remove` an entity, this state transition should be propagated from parent to child, not the other way around.

In this case, you need to move that functionally to the `Group` entity, something like this:

```java
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Entity(name="Group")
public class Group {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "GROUP_ID")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="NAME")
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(
            targetEntity = Product.class,
            mappedBy = "groupId",
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY, // Always prefer LAZY initialized Collections to EAGER ones
            orphanRemoval = true
    )
    private List<Product> products = new ArrayList<>();

    public Group(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void addProduct(Product product){
      product.setGroupId(this);
      this.products.add(product);
    }

    public void removeProduct(Product product){
      product.setGroupId(null);
      this.products.remove(product);
    }
```

If you want to `remove` a `Product`, you only need to invoke the `removeProduct` method and `save` the parent entity:

```java
Group group = new Group("group1");
Product product = new Product("test", "testProduct", 100.0);

group.addProduct(product);

groupDao.save(group);
```

On the other hand, we have the many-to-many relation between `Product` and `CartEntity`.

First, if you configure the entity `CartEntity` with `Cascade.ALL` as in your example:

```java
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "carts")
private List<Product> productsList = new ArrayList<>();
```

It will have a probably undesired effect: if you remove the `CartEntity`, it will remove all the `Product`s associated with the entity as well, even if other `CartEntity`s are still associated to them. Vlad Mihalcea explain it in great detail in [this article](https://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-jpa-and-hibernate-cascade-types/).

To avoid that problem, the best option will be just define the relationship as follows:

```java
@ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE}, mappedBy = "carts")
private List<Product> productsList = new ArrayList<>();
```

This will give us a `CartEntity` like this:

```java
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity(name = "cart")
public class CartEntity {

    @Id
    @NotNull
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "CART_ID")
    private Long id;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE}, mappedBy = "carts")
    private List<Product> productsList = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addProduct(Product product) {
        productsList.add(product);
        product.getCarts().add(this);
    }

    public void removeProduct(Product product) {
        productsList.remove(product);
        product.getCarts().remove(this);
    }

    public void removeProducts() {
        for(Product product : new ArrayList<>(products)) {
            removeProduct(product);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        CartEntity that = (CartEntity) o;
        return id.equals(that.id);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(id);
    }
}
```

Please, note the inclusion of the `removeProduct` and `removeProducts` methods.

With this code, if you need to remove a `CartEntity`, just do the following:

```java
cart.removeProducts();
cartDao.remove(cart);
```

And if you need to `remove` a `Product` from the `CartEntity` (will only remove the relation):

```java
cart.removeProduct(product);
cartDao.save(cart);
```

If you need to propagate the `Product` `remove` to the `CartEntity`, I think that the best option will be create a business method that takes care of the whole process. Think in something like:

```java
public void removeProduct(Product product){
  Group group = product.getGroupId();
  group.removeProduct(product);

  final List<CartEntity> carts = product.getCarts();

  if (carts != null) {
    for(CartEntity cart : new ArrayList<>(carts)) {
      cart.removeProduct(product);
      cartDao.save(cart);
    }
  }

  groupDao.save(group);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**It will remove the association, you just need to do small adjustments.**

1. **1:N.** When you remove `Product`, you **don't have to do anything else** in order to remove its association with `Group`, because **the product itself holds the association** (in DB column `product.group_id`). You just **need to commit the transaction**. And next time when you load a group from the DB it for sure will not contain this product.
2. **N:M**. There is **no way to automatically remove the association** because it is stored in a separate table and you don't have a separate entity for it. (YOU SHOULD NOT USE `CascadeType.ALL` for N:M relations). What you want to do is **remove the association before you remove the product.** Just add another helper method to `Product`.

```java
public void removeFromCarts() {
        carts.forEach(c -> c.getProducts().remove(this));
        carts.clear();
}
```

So finally, in order to remove a product and all the associations with it. You will need to do the following:

```java
        product.removeFromCarts();
        productDao.deleteById(productId); // not sure why you remove by id (not pass object)
```

**please note that you need to commit transaction and close the session. So you cannot rely on the test. In real app when you do what I described, it will work*

***N:M is tricky. For instance, you should better use `Set` instead of `List` to avoid unexpected SQL under the hood. Also going down the road, I recommend you to consider splitting N:M into two N:1 and 1:M and have a dedicated Entity for a link table*

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I follow. Hibernate does not automatically maintain the inverse association for you. You can [make it sensitive to changes on the owning side of the association](https://dzone.com/articles/hibernate-bytecode-enhancement-association-managem), but that's as far as it goes.

As to why your test fails, `cartDaoStub.findById(cartId)` probably returns the same copy of the `CartEntity` that you already have loaded into the persistence context. Try calling `entityManager.flush()` followed by `entityManager.clear()` before making the assertion and the issue will probably go away.